# Crystal Reports XI splitting array into string

Tags: crystal-reports

With the SPLIT function, I'm trying to split an array of vertical bar delimited names (firstname lastname) and return a string of names (***initial*** lastname) each on a new line.  Thanks for the assistance.

--data

Tom Smith | Tim Jones  | Mary Adams

--output

T Smith

T Jones

M Adams

Comment: did you want them in 1 object or 3 objects?  1 object with carriage return?

Comment: 1 object w/ carriage return - thanks - I was trying a nested for loop but couldn't get it to work...